# rpm build based on os

Tags: linux

I am new in building rpms where I need to build a rpm which will install 2 separate set of files based on OS version such as rhel5 and rhel6.
Is it possible?
If yes, how?
If not, I assume I need to create 2 separate rpms such as rpm-a-rhel5.rpm and rpm-a-rhel6.rpm. But how can I make sure that rpm-a-rhel6.rpm cannot be installed in rhel5 and vice versa.
What I need to check in my spec file for case1/case2?
Any idea, please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

RPM spec files have conditionals and variables that can allow you to build an RPM that will change what's done or installed based on the release.

```
%if 0%{?rhel} = 6
Requires: 
%endif
```

However, running `rpmbuild` won't cut it when doing this. You'll need to use `mock`. I highly recommend reading fedora's rpm guidelines.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

As for your other question, you cannot prevent installation of an RPM based on distro. It's normally up to a requirement of the package to cause a dependency block. A dependency that does this: `Requires: redhat-release >= 6.3`.